# solve the difference using a value table

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve the difference using a value table
$\frac{11}{2\left(x+2\right)}$ $\le$ $1+\frac{5}{2\left(x+2\right)^2}$

I dont understand how the table would look like $-2$ is odef and from $-1$ to $2$ is not true and only from $3$ to $\infty$ is the difference true.

[image]

\begin{array}{cccc}
& x<−2 & −2<x<−3/2 & −3/2<x<3 & x>3 & x=2\\
2(x+2) & - & + & + & + & 0\\
2(x+2)^2 & + & + & + & + & 0\\
\ \frac{11}{2\left(x+2\right)}\le 1+\frac{5}{2\left(x+2\right)^2} & - & + & - & -& undefined
\end{array}

Comment: Please use punctuation and clear language in your text. What is "odef"?

Comment: So I guess you're trying to say that at $x=-2$, the expressions are not defined. That's true. But then you say "from -1 to 2" ... What are these values? Graphically, it's easy to see that the two graphs intersect at $x=-1.5$ and $x=3$. So I would say these are some values that you'd be interested in. In summary, there are four different regions that you should check: $x<-2$ , $-2<x < -\frac{3}{2}$, $-\frac{3}{2}<x<3$ and $x>3$.

Comment: added a table dont know if I am doing it right tho

Comment: sry for that removed it

Comment: Note that you can set $y=\frac1{2(x+2)}$ and then factorize the inequality as $0<1-11y+10y^2=(1-y)(1-10y)$.